# Isomorphisms in finite abelian groups 1

Tags: abelian-groups

True of false? If G and H are two groups with the same order and both
are abelian, then they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

Am implication of this is that every finite abelian group is isomorphic to some cyclic group, which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{HINT-}$  Consider $\mathbb{Z_4}$ and $\mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2}$. So FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Any finite abelian group is isomorphic to direct product of prime power orders. So I can apply this for these two groups we get they are not  isomorphic. Because if G is cyclic and H is not.